# TableColumn #setCellValueFactory For Class With HashMaps

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, tableview

I have a custom class `BasicDataSet` which contains a `HashMap` needing to be rendered (and updatable) to a JavaFX `TableView`. A `BasicDataSet` object represents a row and any hash map values missing for that column are rendered as empty strings in the table.

A `BasicDataSet` contains the hash map of dataPoints, name, and tagName. When the `ArrayList<BasicDataSet>` is passed into the method all the keys from each hash map object are pulled, and filtered for duplicates. These keys will become the column header values and are used to pull data out of the hash map (in the factory).

My problem is creating a cell value factory which does this. This method is suppose to create a `TableView` object for my view controller.

```
    public static TableView<BasicDataSet> renderTableFromBasicDataSets(ArrayList<BasicDataSet> sets) {

    TableView<BasicDataSet> tableView = new TableView<>();

    // create all keys required for the collection of basic data sets
    // and remove duplicates using a stream
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    keys.add("name");
    keys.add("tagName");
    for(BasicDataSet basicDataSet : sets) {
        keys.addAll(basicDataSet.getDataPointKeys());
    }
    keys = new ArrayList<>(keys.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));

    // create all required columns using keys to label column names
    // then declare their cellValueFactories
    for(String columnHeader : keys) {
        TableColumn<BasicDataSet, String> tempColumn = new TableColumn<>(columnHeader);
        tempColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
            for(BasicDataSet set : sets) {
                if(columnHeader.equals("name")) {
                    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(set.getName());
                } else if(columnHeader.equals("tagName")) {
                    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(set.getTagName());
                } else {
                    final String tempVal = set.getDataPoint(columnHeader);
                    if(tempVal != null) {
                        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(set.getDataPoint(columnHeader));
                    } else {
                        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("");
                    }
                }
            }
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("");
        });
        tableView.getColumns().add(tempColumn);
    }

    return tableView;
}
```

When this code runs only the columns with the headers are rendered. No data is displayed.

I am new to Lambda functions so any extra details regarding the factory would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: [Here](https://github.com/Collinz4/TableViewExample) you will find a small example project on GitHub.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Sedrick Give me about 20 minutes and I will have an example.

Comment: @Sedrick I have created a reproducible example in GitHub. Link is at the bottom of the question in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cell value factory needs to make use of its `data` argument.  That argument is the actual row data for which the TableColumn is requesting a value.

Ignore `sets`.  You should not be looking at *all* of your data, only the single row of data represented by `data`.

This means that your code can simply remove the `for (BasicDataSet set : sets)` loop, and can obtain `set` from `data.getValue()`:

```
tempColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
    BasicDataSet set = data.getValue();
    if (columnHeader.equals("name")) {
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(set.getName());
    } else if (columnHeader.equals("tagName")) {
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(set.getTagName());
    } else {
        final String tempVal = set.getDataPoint(columnHeader);
        if(tempVal != null) {
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(set.getDataPoint(columnHeader));
        } else {
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("");
        }
    }
});
```

Ideally, you should design your BasicDataSet class so it provides its data as properties or other observable values, so your cell value factory doesn’t have to keep creating temporary ‘disembodied’ properties:

```
public class BasicDataSet {
    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();
    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper tagName = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();
    private final ObservableMap<String, String> dataPoints =
        FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    private final ObservableSet<String> keys =
        FXCollections.observableSet();

    public BasicDataSet(String name,
                        String tagName) {

        this.name.set(name);
        this.tagName.set(tagName);

        dataPoints.addListener(
            (MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends String> c) -> {
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                keys.remove(c.getKey());
            }
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                keys.add(c.getKey());
            }
        });
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty tagNameProperty() {
        return tagName.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public String getTagName() {
        return tagName.get();
    }

    public ObservableMap<String> getObservableDataPoints() {
        return dataPoints;
    }

    public ObservableSet<String> getDataPointKeys() {
        return keys;
    }

    public StringBinding getObservableDataPoint(String key) {
        return Bindings.stringValueAt(dataPoints, key);
    }

    public String getDataPoint(String key) {
        return getObservableDataPoint(key).get();
    }
}
```

This allows you to pass the properties directly to the cell value factory:

```
tempColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
    BasicDataSet set = data.getValue();
    if (columnHeader.equals("name")) {
        return set.nameProperty();
    } else if (columnHeader.equals("tagName")) {
        return set.tagNameProperty();
    } else {
        return set.getObservableDataPoint(columnHeader);
    }
});
```

Comment: This makes much more sense. When I run your first block of code on the debugger, it will not execute the lambda function. This was happening before with my code as well. I believe this is one of the reasons why the table is not updating.

Comment: My mistake, I needed to also add the objects into the table AFTER the `for(String columnHeader : keys)` loop executed using `tableView.getItems().addAll(sets);`. This solves the issue with the table not populating. Thank you @VGR for the answer on how to properly setup the factory method. I may change the model to use observable values if it serializes with Jackson correctly.